# flex warning multi charecter charecter const

Tags: c, warnings

**edit**: it was indeed the check for '\r\n' it confused me because the line of the error was the counter and not the "if"

I have a weird problem while working with flex, 
in this code i'm trying to count how much lines a comment last and for this i change a counter inside an "if" statement

```
void commentHandler(int line){
    int counter = 0;

    if (1 == line){
        printf("%d COMMENT 1\n",yylineno);
    }
    else{
    for(int i=2 ; i< yyleng-2 ; i++){
        if('/' ==yytext[i] && '*' == yytext[i+1]){
            errorHandler(ERROR_NESTED_COM);
        }
        if('\n' == yytext[i] || '\r\n' == yytext[i]){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d COMMENT %d\n", yylineno - counter, counter + 1);
    }
}
```

but when i compile it it shows the following warning:

```
warning: multi-charcter charecter constant [-Wmultichar]
```

as this is my HW i can't ignore warnings but no matter what i put in there it shows the same warning which  i never seen before and i don't really know what went wrong.

is this some wrapping of flex that contradicts with it? I played with the name of counter but it didn't change.

what does the warning means?

Comment: Hint: How could one character be *both* a carriage return and a newline combined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test characters individually, not in aggregate, but in this case all you really need is:

```
if ('\n' == yytext[i]) {
```

As rici points out, the `\r` check is actually extraneous.

Comment: well isn't the last paragraph unnecessary in *this case*, yytext should be null-terminated, not?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala If it is, you're safe. If not, be careful. It's been a while since I've used lex, so I'm not sure if it's terminated or just a raw buffer with size.

Comment: The loop itself seems to handle the buffer bounds, since the loop condition is `i< yyleng-2`

Comment: @tadman: flex goes to a lot of trouble to guarantee that `yytext` is NUL-terminated. Posix insists on that (and, I think, 99% of the programs built with flex would break if it weren't the case.)

Comment: @rici Thanks for confirming. Good to know!

Comment: No worries. What's more important, now that I look at it, is that your code double-counts \r\n. The \r check is completely unnecessary; just count \n.

Comment: @rici This is to handle LF or CRLF delimited files, presumably. You don't want to skip characters like `">\n"`.

Comment: No `\n` is skipped. The code counts every `\n` including the ones preceded by `\r`. But as you have written it, it also counts `\r` if it is followed by `\n`. So a `\r\n` line ending is double counted.

Comment: @rici I see what you're saying now. It needs to kick the pointer ahead in the CRLF case.

Comment: No, it just needs to leave out the `\r` check . The following `\n` will be counted anyway, so also checking for `\r` is unnecessary.

Comment: @rici Updated accordingly.

Comment: This is the programming equivalent of the [conjunction fallacy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_fallacy) (Tversky & Kahneman, 1983). :-)

Comment: while i would just count \n and be done in any other program, as its my HW and they specifically declared to count each '\r' '\n' '\r\n' as one line i just didn't think further on it and put it all in if,